# MPMoviePlayerController Custom Control

Tags: iphone

Can We make Custom control like the default Slider in MPMoviePlayerController
for forwarding and Backward the movie?

Answer (score 2):

While you can't modify the MPMoviePlayerController class, you can create your own controls to manage movie playback.
The way you do this is, you create a horizontal slider, you set it's minimum value to 0, and the maximum value to the duration property. Create a timer to update the slider's current value every second to the movie's currentPlaybackTime property, like so:

```
    sliderTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateSlider) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and create an IBAction to interact with the slider, to seek a specific time, you will need to add a listener to your slider, like so:

```
    [seeker addTarget:self action:@selector(sliding:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

If you want, you can even create labels that show the current and remaining times, but this is a little messy. Good luck.